# update datagrideview based on another one

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have two datagridviews . The first one contains an ID column. I want to select a row in that datagridview and have the second dgv update based on that ID

please help me

Comment: Search "Master Detail" to get started.

Answer (score 0):

It take a little effort to get these kinds of things up and running, but it's not too bad actually.  Just follow the guild lines highlighted in the link below.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/masterdetail/master-detail-using-a-selectable-master-gridview-with-a-details-detailview-cs

[image]

[image]